# Obtaining scrollTop on iOS during momentum scrolling in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, overflow

Using cordova, using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch`,  momentum/inertia scrolling can be enabled on a page. However, this causes problems obtaining the scroll position.

On Android, scrollTop correctly updates with the current position while scrolling. However, on iOS, it appears that scrollTop is only updated on the completing the scroll.

Is there anyway to obtain/compute the value of scrollTop?

Comment: From a comment on the question this was marked a duplicate of : `there is nothing like a continuous event of scrolling being triggered while the pan happens there just an onScroll at the end of the gesture.`

Comment: https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/03/20/workaround-for-mobile-safari-scrolltop-not-updating-during-scroll/ may provide a workaround, but I did not get it to work